# Collaborating on a wordpress web application with a database hosted with aws

Tags: wordpress, github

a group of four need to create a web application using Wordpress. I am using wamp to host the website locally and I have connected it to a database created using aws RDS. The goal is to upload my project to github and have all members be able to work on the app on their personal computers while being able to retrieve and modify data from the same database. I tried cloning to web app on my second computer but the website would not load. Any thoughts or recommendations?

Comment: Any errors you have? It's better to ask this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/